# Extjs: how to use object key value with space in extjs tpl?

Tags: html, extjs, sencha-touch, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

```
 CODE :
 var data={"today date":'12-02-2014' ,"created date":'10-2-1014'}

   tpl= new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl for=".">','<p>{today date}</p>','<p>{created date}</p>','</tpl>');
```

here I have attached the sample code.

Comment: you use variable inside `{...}` in tpl. As it is variable, you can not have spaces. You can use underscore `_`.

Comment: thank you @NandkumarTekale...But Iam not using the static variable to edit the key value Iam receiving it from web service that the problem i am facing with.Please give the solution for it.Thank you once again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: don't.

```
var data = {"today date":'12-02-2014' ,"created date":'10-2-1014'};

// notice udpated variable names
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl for=".">','<p>{today_date}</p>','<p>{created_date}</p>','</tpl>');

var fixedData = {};
Ext.each(Ext.Object.getKeys(data), function(key) {
    fixedData[key.replace(/ /g, '_')] = data[key];
});

// test
alert(tpl.apply(fixedData));
```